# SQL tables design one table or two tables

Tags: database, database-design

I have a table with about 20 columns. It works well, its related to other table many to many, but it works fine and design is good so far.

Now I need to store another type of data, which has almost same columns, it has 15 columns that are basically same, but 5 columns are completelly different
between this 2 types. So how do I do it 
1. do I store it in one table (by adding new Columns in first table -> this way some 5 columns would be null depending which type of data we save), or
2. split it to 2 tables and than each table has same columns repeated in other table
3. some other way ?

COLUMNS CASE 1 - STORE IN ONE SAME TABLE

```
ID            INTEGER
Description   NVARCHAR(max)
Value         FLOAT
ValueEUR      FLOAT
ValueUSD      FLOAT
YearOfBuilt   SMALLINT
New           BIT
Requirements  NVARCHAR(max)
FIELD A1
FIELD A2
FIELD A3
FIELD A4
FIELD A5
FK_TypeID     INT
```

do I add 5 new fields for other document type to above table:

```
FIELD B1      FLOAT
FIELD B2      FLOAT
FIELD B3      FLOAT
FIELD B4      FLOAT
FIELD B5      FLOAT
```

In this case if I save data for type 1
saved field value would be **null** for columns `FIELD B1`, ... `FIELD B5`.
Well, it would work, but than some fields would be empty, depending on type.

or do I make table design as in case 2 below

COLUMNS CASE 2 - STORE IN TWO TABLES

TABLE 1

```
ID            INTEGER
Description   NVARCHAR(max)
Value         FLOAT
ValueEUR      FLOAT
ValueUSD      FLOAT
YearOfBuilt   SMALLINT
New           BIT
Requirements  NVARCHAR(max)
FIELD A1
FIELD A2
FIELD A3
FIELD A4
FIELD A5
FK_TypeID     INT
```

TABLE 2 - Repeating same columns but excluding columns not needed for this table

```
ID            INTEGER
Description   NVARCHAR(max)
Value         FLOAT
ValueEUR      FLOAT
ValueUSD      FLOAT
YearOfBuilt   SMALLINT
New           BIT
Requirements  NVARCHAR(max)
FIELD B1      FLOAT
FIELD B2      FLOAT
FIELD B3      FLOAT
FIELD B4      FLOAT
FIELD B5      FLOAT
FK_TypeID     INT
```

Now in this case 2, I would repeat same columns but exclude columns not needed. This means same columns names, however data are stored to save space (no null values).

Which approach would be better?
Or is there another way to do it? I am not beginner in database design.

Answer (score 1):

Generally we split into two tables - this is called Database Normalisation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Especially so if the same-columns are related in some way eg if they are contact details for two different kinds of people (eg customers vs employees) then you can name the new table after that (eg the new database would be called contact_details or something).

Basically: you're not saving anything (not space or optimising performance or anything) by storing it all in the same table. All you're doing is making the data more confusing for yourself or other developers to understand in the future.

Also, think of future queries you create - every one of them will have to filter out the data that's not relevant - which makes every single query more complex. Better to store different things in different tables and make it easier to understand-at-a-glance what's going on in your database+code

Comment: ok, I am beginner. So, it does not matter that I repeat same 15 columns as in first table? Columns are not related in some way between two tables, as this are basically different data, though column names are same.

Comment: Ah, right then yes, it does not matter that the column names are the same... if the data is different, then definitely don't share the same table just because column-names are the same. Keep them separate.

Comment: basically: you're not saving anything (not space or optimising performance or anything) by storing it all in the same table. All you're doing is making the data more confusing for yourself or other developers to understand the data. Also, think of future queries you create - every one of them will have to filter out the data that's not relevant - which makes every single query more complex. Better to store different things in different tables and make it easier to understand-at-a-glance what's going on in your database+code

Comment: ok, just to clarify it once more. 15 columns (names) are same in both tables, however they dont store same data. For example, we dont have situation that John Doe is in both tables, since tables store completely different data. So there will be no duplication of data.Thanks

Comment: That's... not what i meant about duplication of data. It's not about John Doe being in both tables... it's about whether the data is the same kind of thing - eg address fields in one table and address fields in the other table. If they are both address columns, then the best thing is to create an "addresses" table and both your tables will reference into that table (eg  table 1 will have an `address_id` column, and in table 2 there will also be an `address_id` column).

Comment: @ExpertLoser & TarynEast This has nothing to do with normalization, which is about replacing a table by projections of it that always join to it. It does have to do with *subtypes in databases/SQL*.

Comment: @Taryn East ok, thanks. Joining it into one table and than making 2 other tables additionally, makes things more complex regarding Entity Framework 6. I need to think about it is it a must to do this way

Comment: @Taryn East Can I actually split table into 2 tables and use one to one relationship?

Comment: @philipxy can I use one to one relationship in this case for example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I'd just add that having to know and choose another table for the same kind of data to avoid filter, isn't always better, and is generally "filtering by table name". 
Depends If you have 2 types & tables or 300. 
It's about competences too:
* data storage design (by storage/DB/HW/cloud guru) 
* query design for UI (SQL guru) (less "energy" from UI designer) 
* UI design
Could create a view for viewing the data.
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = <type_n>;  
SELECT * FROM view_type_n;        #filter by view

UI code would anyway have: data(type_n) and data_n();